make selected uiview increase in size with slider movement
In my code when the user hits the rectB button it adds small uiviews. When the user select the specific view it should increase or decrease in size based on the slider. My code below works sometimes when I click on the specific box enough time but it does not work right now. I have added a gif of what I am looking for. This gif is not representative of my core below. It is the desired output.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var rectB = UIButton()
    
  
    
    var slider = UISlider()
    
    var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
    

    var ht = -90
    var ww = 80
    
    var widthOfSquare = 30
    var selectNum = Int()
    var currentView: UIView?
    
    
    var count: Int = 0
    


    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider.value = 0.50
        [rectB , slider,  ].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            if let textfield = $0 as? UITextField {
                textfield.textAlignment = .center
           
            }
            
            if let label = $0 as? UILabel {
                
                label.textAlignment = .center
            }
            if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            }
            
        }//below
        
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
         
            
            
            slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectB.topAnchor),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            
            
            
            
          
            
            rectB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            rectB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            rectB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0),
            rectB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
          
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sxBTN), for: .valueChanged)
        
        rectB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rectangeBox), for: .touchDown)
    
        
     
        
        
        
        
        
        rectB.setTitle("Rectangle", for: .normal)
        
     
        
    }
   

   
    
    
    @objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        currentView = gesture.view
    }
    
    @objc func sxBTN(sender : UISlider){
        
        
        
        if selectNum == 1 {
          
            
            currentView?.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(slider.value) /   (currentView?.bounds.size.width)! * 100
            currentView?.bounds.size.height = CGFloat(slider.value) / (currentView?.bounds.size.height)! * 100
            

            
            print("in 1")
            
            return
        }
        

        if selectNum == 2 {//opacity
            
            let diff = slider.maximumValue-slider.minimumValue
            
            
            currentView?.alpha = CGFloat(slider.value/diff)
            
            print("2")
            return
        }

        
        
        
    }
  
    
    @objc func rectangeBox(){
        selectNum = 1
        let subview = UIImageView()
        
        
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)
        
        
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sxBTN(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        slider.minimumValue = 10
        slider.maximumValue = 200
        
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ww), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        subview.tag = count
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
        
        
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        
        count += 1
        ht += 50
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
 
    
    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        
        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
    
}


I don't think you should call addTarget to your UISlider as well as setting the minimumValue and maximumValue in your button action. You already have addTarget in viewDidLoad.
currentView?.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(slider.value) /   (currentView?.bounds.size.width)! * 100 this is also wrong, you should not divide the width and height by itself.

You can use this code. You may need to reset the slider when you select new rectangle.
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var rectB = UIButton()
    var slider = UISlider()
    
    var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
    

    var ht = -90
    var ww = 80
    
    var widthOfSquare = 30
    var selectNum = Int()
    var currentView: UIView?
    var count: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider.value = 0.50
        [rectB , slider].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            if let textfield = $0 as? UITextField {
                textfield.textAlignment = .center
           
            }
            
            if let label = $0 as? UILabel {
                
                label.textAlignment = .center
            }
            if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            }
            
        }//below
        
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectB.topAnchor),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            rectB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            rectB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            rectB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0),
            rectB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
          
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sxBTN), for: .valueChanged)
        slider.minimumValue = 1
        slider.maximumValue = 3
        
        rectB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rectangeBox), for: .touchDown)
        rectB.setTitle("Rectangle", for: .normal)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        currentView = gesture.view
    }
    
    @objc func sxBTN(sender : UISlider){
        
        if selectNum == 1 {
          
            currentView?.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(ww) * CGFloat(slider.value)
            currentView?.bounds.size.height = CGFloat(35) * CGFloat(slider.value)
           
            print("in 1")
            
            return
        }
        

        if selectNum == 2 {//opacity
            
            let diff = slider.maximumValue-slider.minimumValue
            
            
            currentView?.alpha = CGFloat(slider.value/diff)
            
            print("2")
            return
        }
    }
  
    
    @objc func rectangeBox(){
        selectNum = 1
        let subview = UIImageView()
        
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)
        
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ww), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        subview.tag = count
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
        
        
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        
        count += 1
        ht += 50
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
 
    
    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        
        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
    
}




This does not work this does nothing to affect the size.

It's not entirely clear how you want to size the added subviews, so I'll make a couple assumptions:

you're setting your slider .minimumValue = 10 and .maximumValue = 200, so we'll use that as the width range
your start size is width: ww //(80) and height: 35, so we will keep that aspect ratio when sizing
we want to scale the selected view from its center



Here is your modified code (and cleaned up a bit):
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var rectB: UIButton = UIButton()
    var slider: UISlider = UISlider()
    var arrTextFields: [UIView] = []
    
    var ht: CGFloat = -90
    var ww: CGFloat = 80
    
    var selectNum: Int = 0
    
    var currentView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            // if we set currentView to nil, don't try to get its frame
            if let cv = currentView {
                slider.setValue(Float(cv.frame.width), animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var count: Int = 0

    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider.value = 0.50
        [rectB , slider,  ].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }
        rectB.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        slider.backgroundColor = .systemYellow

        // let's respect the safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectB.topAnchor),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            
            rectB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            rectB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            rectB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0),
            rectB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sxBTN), for: .valueChanged)
        
        rectB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rectangeBox), for: .touchDown)
        
        rectB.setTitle("Rectangle", for: .normal)

        // set the slider properties here
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sxBTN(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        slider.minimumValue = 10
        slider.maximumValue = 200

    }
    
    @objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // safely unwrap optional
        guard let v = gesture.view else { return }
        view.bringSubviewToFront(v)
        currentView = v
    }
    
    @objc func sxBTN(sender : UISlider){
        
        // if we don't have currentView assigned, don't do anything
        guard let cv = currentView else { return }
        
        if selectNum == 1 {
            
            // rectangle sizing
            //  width = slider value (it will be between 10 and 200)
            //  height = width * original ratio (35.0 / ww)
            
            let newWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(slider.value)
            let newHeight: CGFloat = newWidth * (35.0 / ww)

            // assuming we want to scale from the center
            //  get the current center
            let currentCenterPoint: CGPoint = cv.center
            
            // set the new frame size
            cv.frame.size = .init(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
            
            // reset the frame center
            cv.center = currentCenterPoint
            
            // don't do this
            //currentView?.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(slider.value) /   (currentView?.bounds.size.width)! * 100
            //currentView?.bounds.size.height = CGFloat(slider.value) / (currentView?.bounds.size.height)! * 100
            
            print("in 1")
            
            return
        }
        
        if selectNum == 2 {//opacity
            
            let diff = slider.maximumValue-slider.minimumValue
            
            
            currentView?.alpha = CGFloat(slider.value/diff)
            
            print("2")
            return
        }
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func rectangeBox(){
        selectNum = 1
        let subview = UIImageView()
        
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(subview)
        
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ww), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
        
        // cycle through colors
        subview.backgroundColor = colors[count % colors.count]
        subview.tag = count

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        count += 1
        ht += 50
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        
        // set currentView to the newly added subview
        //  so we can use the slider without needing to drag or tap the new subview
        currentView = subview
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // safely unwrap optional
        guard let draggedView = gesture.view else { return }
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
        
        // set currentView when dragged, so we don't have to tap it again
        currentView = draggedView
    }
    
}

