change the size of selected uiview
In my swift code a button adds a uiview to the view controller and when the slider is moved it adjusts the size. The problem is it can only affect the size of the most recently added uiview. I want the code to be able to adjust anytime a uiview is selected the size can be changed. You can see what is going on in the gif below.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var rectB = UIButton()
    var bottomSlider = UISlider()
    
    var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
    
    var ww = 80
    var currentView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        bottomSlider.value = 1
        [rectB, bottomSlider].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            }
        }
        
        // Initialize sliderX's properties
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bottomSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectB.topAnchor),
            bottomSlider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08),
            bottomSlider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            bottomSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            rectB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            rectB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08),
            rectB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            rectB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        ])
        
        bottomSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sxBTN), for: .valueChanged)
        bottomSlider.minimumValue = 1
        bottomSlider.maximumValue = 3
        
        rectB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rectangeBox), for: .touchDown)
        rectB.setTitle("Rectangle", for: .normal)
    }
    
    @objc func rectangeBox() {
        let subview = UIImageView()
        
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)
        
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ww), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        // Add label with text "hello"
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "hello"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.sizeToFit()
        
        // Position the label at the bottom middle of the subview
        label.frame = CGRect(
            x: (subview.frame.width - label.frame.width) / 2,
            y: subview.frame.height - label.frame.height,
            width: label.frame.width,
            height: label.frame.height
        )
        
        subview.addSubview(label)
        
        // Automatically select the new rectangle
        currentView = subview
    }
    
    @objc func sxBTN(sender: UISlider) {
        guard let currentView = currentView else { return }
        
        let newWidth = CGFloat(ww) * CGFloat(sender.value)
        let newHeight = CGFloat(35) * CGFloat(sender.value)
        
        currentView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        
        // Find the label in the currentView
        if let label = currentView.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UILabel }).first {
            // Check if the new width is greater than half the width of the view controller
            let viewControllerWidth = view.bounds.width
            if newWidth >= viewControllerWidth / 2 {
                label.text = "2"
            } else {
                label.text = "1"
            }
            label.textAlignment = .center
            // Reposition the label to be at the bottom center
            label.frame = CGRect(
                x: (newWidth - label.frame.width) / 2,
                y: newHeight - label.frame.height,
                width: label.frame.width,
                height: label.frame.height
            )
        }
    }

    @objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        currentView = gesture.view
        // Set slider value to match the size of the selected box
        if let currentView = currentView {
            bottomSlider.value = Float(currentView.bounds.width) / Float(ww)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
}


I tested your code and I didn't get your issue...

only the last added uiview can be changed try it with 3 boxes you will see the problem. I want to be able to edit all 3 of them with adjustable size.

this is because tap gesture works like UIControlEvents.touchUpInside, you have to lift your finger up first for it to trigger your handleTapGestured function. If you drag immediately after tapping on the view, you won't be able to assign gesture.view to your currentView. You can just simply put currentView = gesture.view in your handlePanGestured function.

Is this the same as your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78885960/make-selected-uiview-increase-in-size-with-slider-movement
